# The Hidden expression used in textbox 'CurrentNumPlayers' returned a data type that is not valid

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

When i run this report on report server i get no error but when i put code on internet portal i get error

> The Hidden expression used in textbox 'CurrentNumPlayers' returned a
>   data type that is not valid.

Hidden expression in SSRS 2008 is:

```
=NOT(Fields!IsGroup.Value)
```

IsGroup is defined in sql like

```
[IsGroup] BIT NOT NULL,
```

Is a bit strange because on one server it works fine on other i get this error. What can be the cause for this behavior ?

Comment: Are two servers pointing to two different databases? It may be possible `isGroup` defined as two different data types in two system. Another test you can do is print `Fields!IsGroup.Value` and see what value it shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that many applications/contexts do not recognise the sql server data type bit as equivalent to a boolean, but rather interpret it as an integer.

The issue can be remedied by rewriting your expression as the following:

```
=NOT(Fields!IsGroup.Value = 1)
```

Or even:

```
=(Fields!IsGroup.Value = 0)
```